# using http requester i am able to send keys and values but when i am sending the same url/encoded values through browser it couldent accept values

Tags: php, mysql, json

using http requester i am able to send keys and values but when i am sending the same url/encoded values through browser it couldent accept values.
thrwing errors below:

error:

> Notice: Undefined index: email in filepath/filename.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in filepath/filename.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: username in filepath/filename.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: age in filepath/filename.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined index: gender in filepath/filename.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: address in filepath/filename.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: city in filepath/filename.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: country in filepath/filename.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: pincode in filepath/filename.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: mobile in filepath/filename.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: roleid in filepath/filename.php on line 17
>
> {"status":"error","message":"Missing required field"}

My code:

```
<?php 


require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$pincode = $_POST["pincode"];
$mobile = $_POST["mobile"];
$roleid = $_POST["roleid"];

$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($username) || empty($pincode) || empty($gender) || empty($mobile))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User already exists";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password); // I do this, so that user password cannot be read even by me

$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password,$username,$age,$gender,$address,$city,$country,$pincode,$mobile,$roleid);

if($result)
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is Registered";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use $_REQUEST for getting post data which better than $_GET AND $_POST request. 
e.g. 
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

OR

Some time server not handle post data such as data posted from mobile device service inform of body request than you may below :

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);

Answer (score 1):

You may also used following for exception handling with isset() function.
CODE :

```
<?php 
require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");
$email=isset($_POST["email"])&&$_POST["email"]!=NULL?$_POST["email"]:"";
$password=isset($_POST["password"])&&$_POST["password"]!=NULL?$_POST["password"]:"";
$username=isset($_POST["username"])&&$_POST["username"]!=NULL?$_POST["username"]:"";
$age=isset($_POST["age"])&&$_POST["age"]!=NULL?$_POST["age"]:"";
$gender=isset($_POST["gender"])&&$_POST["gender"]!=NULL?$_POST["gender"]:"";
$address=isset($_POST["address"])&&$_POST["address"]!=NULL?$_POST["address"]:"";
$city=isset($_POST["city"])&&$_POST["city"]!=NULL?$_POST["city"]:"";
$country=isset($_POST["country"])&&$_POST["country"]!=NULL?$_POST["country"]:"";
$pincode=isset($_POST["pincode"])&&$_POST["pincode"]!=NULL?$_POST["pincode"]:"";
$mobile=isset($_POST["mobile"])&&$_POST["mobile"]!=NULL?$_POST["mobile"]:"";
$roleid=isset($_POST["roleid"])&&$_POST["roleid"]!=NULL?$_POST["roleid"]:"";
$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($username) || empty($pincode) || empty($gender) || empty($mobile))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User already exists";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password); // I do this, so that user password cannot be read even by me

$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password,$username,$age,$gender,$address,$city,$country,$pincode,$mobile,$roleid);

if($result)
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is Registered";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao->closeConnection();
```

?>

Comment: but now it is throwing an "{"status":"error","message":"Missing required field"}" when i am posting values from browser.

Inspite of this, using http requester, values are get inserted

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you're sending through browser it's using GET method ($_GET)..not POST

That's why your $_POST is empty (undefined index for $_POST["email"])

You can submit using form with method POST

Answer (score 0):

there might be 2 reasons why you get this error, first - you try to assign variables from `$_POST` before you send the request, in this case wrap your code in `if` statement, `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ //your code`, and second, as @parpar said, you might sending `GET` request, while you need `POST` method.